# Quickly update array less lines

Tags: delphi

I have 48 numbers I want to put into an array.  Currently I could do it like so

```
  Tarcher[i] := 20;
  Tarcher[2] := 24;
  Tarcher[3] := 29;
  Tarcher[4] := 35;
```

how could I add the numbers , shorter code to the array?
thanks
Glen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the required values do not fit a formula, then you might consider

```
const
  Tarcher_init    : array[1..48] of integer
                  = (20,24,29,35,5,6,7,8,9,61,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,
                     1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,
                     1,2,3,4,5,6,7,84);
var
  Tarcher         : array[1..48] of integer;
  i               : integer;
begin
  for i := low(Tarcher) to high(Tarcher) do
    Tarcher[i] := Tarcher_init[i];
  {OR}
  move(Tarcher_init,Tarcher,sizeof(Tarcher));
end;
```

Naturally, the `move` would be faster.

Comment: I really like this as the values are not a formula.

Comment: @GlenM that is the kind of useful information that you should have presented up front in your question.

Comment: @RemyLebeau actually I did not even think about it being a sequence till other answer said "if it was"  I had to go back and look but it was not.

Comment: Of course, if you define a type for the array, there is no need for the loop. Just declare the var and the constant of the same type, and you can assign the constant to the var directly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau is it possible to have a page of just const,  then include them in the main program?  Everything I search just shows on to use constants. Still new and not sure if this is even possible. I would ask another question on SO but scared ill get banned for dumb questions.

Comment: @GlenM not quite sure what you are asking. I think you are looking for a unit that just contains `const` values in its `interface`, and then you can include that unit in the `uses` clause of other units and use the `const` values as needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a constant. If you pre-define the type of the array, you can simply assign that:

```
type
  ArchArray = array[0..47] of Integer;
```

Now define the constant:

```
const
  Arches: ArchArray = 
  (  // 48 values here
     1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 33 ....
     ... 33
  );
```

And then you can do (**no need for a loop**):

```
var
  Tarcher: ArchArray;
begin
  Tarcher := Arches;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of the array values follow the same formula for incrementing from one array slot to the next, then a simple loop will suffice, eg:

```
var
  Tarcher: array[1..48] of integer;
  value, i: integer;

value := 20;
for i := 1 to 48 do
begin
  Tarcher[i] := value;
  inc(value, 3 + i);
end;
```

Result:

```
Tarcher[1] = 20
Tarcher[2] = 24
Tarcher[3] = 29
Tarcher[4] = 35
Tarcher[5] = 42
Tarcher[6] = 50
Tarcher[7] = 59
Tarcher[8] = 69
Tarcher[9] = 80
Tarcher[10] = 92
Tarcher[11] = 105
Tarcher[12] = 119
Tarcher[13] = 134
Tarcher[14] = 150
Tarcher[15] = 167
Tarcher[16] = 185
Tarcher[17] = 204
Tarcher[18] = 224
Tarcher[19] = 245
Tarcher[20] = 267
Tarcher[21] = 290
Tarcher[22] = 314
Tarcher[23] = 339
Tarcher[24] = 365
Tarcher[25] = 392
Tarcher[26] = 420
Tarcher[27] = 449
Tarcher[28] = 479
Tarcher[29] = 510
Tarcher[30] = 542
Tarcher[31] = 575
Tarcher[32] = 609
Tarcher[33] = 644
Tarcher[34] = 680
Tarcher[35] = 717
Tarcher[36] = 755
Tarcher[37] = 794
Tarcher[38] = 834
Tarcher[39] = 875
Tarcher[40] = 917
Tarcher[41] = 960
Tarcher[42] = 1004
Tarcher[43] = 1049
Tarcher[44] = 1095
Tarcher[45] = 1142
Tarcher[46] = 1190
Tarcher[47] = 1239
Tarcher[48] = 1289
```